# Stop CouchDB logging on Android Device?

Tags: android, logging, nosql, couchdb, ektorp

I am using `CouchDB` as the database on my **Android Device**.

Here is the problem that I am facing:

**The amount of space that couchDB takes on Android Device is very large.** - Every time when couchdb starts replication, it logs the replication stats into a `couch.log` file - the size of this file keeps on increasing after every replication.

I do not want to log anything in this file because its a memory overhead on my Android Device. How can I stop logging into this `couch.log` file?

*- I am using Ektorp API for CouchDB on Android.*

Answer (score 1):

Set logging level to `none` in `local.ini` config file and restart CouchDB:

```
[log]
level=none
```

or via HTTP API call (sorry, don't know Java or Ektorp API, but hope you can translate cURL command into it) which doesn't requires server restart:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_config/log/level -d '"none"' -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

This kind of level disables any log messages, even error reports.

Comment: How would I set it for Android Device?